# Error 999999 "The table already exists" "No spatial reference exists" when using "import arcserver"

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, error-999999

I'm hoping someone can help me understand why I'm getting this error. I have a python script tool that throws this error when it is run through the task scheduler:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Image_Processing\Python_Scripts_Automation_CA\Create_Report_Automation.py", line 474, in <module>
    arcpy.RasterCatalogToRasterDataset_management(pathRasterCatalog, scratchGDB + "/raster1", where_clause="Name = '" + sSingleImage + "'")
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\server\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 13319, in RasterCatalogToRasterDataset
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
The table already exists.
No spatial reference exists.
Failed to execute (RasterCatalogToRasterDataset).
```

However, when I run it through arcmap, it runs fine. The only difference between the two instances is when I run it through the task scheduler, I use `import arcserver`, and when I run it through arcmap, I have to comment out that line. At first I thought it was something to do with the raster catalog, but then I started getting the exact same error when I added an `arcpy.Clip_management()` tool to the code, which doesn't use the raster catalog. And I've checked the spatial references on all of the suspect data, and it does exist. So I'm at a loss. Is it something to do with the scratch GDB?

Comment: You should publish your code (or at least part of it) - it is hard to know what is wrong with that without looking at it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out it was something to do with the scratchGDB. When run in arcmap, the tool used a scratch GDB in a known location (i.e. one I set up). When run from the task scheduler, and the `import arcserver` was turned on, it used a scratch GDB in the local app data folder. The arc server scratch GDB had existing data, which was causing overwrite issues.